# It is possible to make snap using Google Maps based on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Vectorized few lines using QGIS with Google Maps as a base. 
If I do not Trabachar with maximum zoom does not respect the topology of the base. 
It is possible to make snap using Google Maps based on QGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot snap to Google Maps or any other raster layer. Snapping only works with vector layers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with Google maps - if you're after a vector dataset, look into the use of openstreetmap data. It may possibly already include what you need. You can download what you need through the OpenStreetMap plugin.